# Declaration of global variables in separate file: compiler conflict

Tags: c, variables, cpp

So I have:

1/ My `myapp.ino` file, that includes `src.h` (implemented in `src.cpp`). Compiled for Arduino Uno.

2/ I also have a `unit-tests.cpp` file that is meant to test functions in `src.cpp`. Compiled for desktop/MacOS.

I don't understand where to declare global variables. They have to be accessed by those three files (I know it's not 100% good practice but it's a simple app).

Simplified example:
`src.h`

```cpp
#ifndef CHAOS_SRC_H
#define CHAOS_SRC_H

extern float min_delta;
extern float max_delta;
extern float min_val;
extern float max_val;
extern float rescale_power;

#endif
```

`src.cpp`

```cpp
#include "src.h"

//float min_delta;
//float max_delta;
//float min_val;
//float max_val;
float rescale_power;
```

`myapp.ino`

```cpp
#include "src.h"

float presets[4][5] =  {
  // MIN_DELTA, MAX_DELTA, MIN_VAL, MAX_VAL
  {0, 500, 0, 30, 1}, // Old tape
  {200, 2000, 0, 255, 1}, // Broken tape
  {0, 500, 90, 100, 3}, // New broken tape (delay time at ~ min)
  {0, 100, 90, 140, 3}, //
};

float min_delta = presets[PRESET][0];
float max_delta = presets[PRESET][1];
float min_val = presets[PRESET][2];
float max_val = presets[PRESET][3];
float rescale_power = presets[PRESET][4];
```

`unit-tests.cpp`

```cpp
#include "src.h"

int main()
{
}
```

When I compile `myapp.ino` for Arduino, the compiler complains `rescale_power` has multiple definitions. So I remove it in `src.cpp` and it works.

But then, when I compile `unit-tests.cpp` for desktop, that one compiler complains about `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  "_rescale_power"`.
Re-adding it solves it.
And so on.

What is the way to go please? Any kind of logic?

Comment: Why downvote please?

Comment: Not sure, but recently [questions have been downvoted than usual.](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/who-is-down-voting-all-and-every-question). The question is up for closure, probably on the grounds that it's more of a C++ question than an Arduino one. I can't tell which thing you're confused about. Error will point out each of the multiple definitions. You've been using `extern`. Do you understand the significance of `extern` in the way that you're using it?

Comment: Isn't it the only way to make the variable accessible from outside?

Comment: And Arduino and g++ compilers and not reacting similarly, so I'm guessing there must be something specific about Arduino.

Comment: Defining a variable multiple times as you have in the shown code will break g++ (or any other c++ compiler for that matter) whether it is launched from the build process or from a more traditional non-Arduino build system. To be clear, I am only telling you that this the wrong tree to bark up. Check Edgar Bonet's answer again, with an understanding that `extern` will cause variables to be *only* **declared** and not *also* **defined** as they are by default.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a header/implementation pair of files, the general rule is
that the implementation *defines* everything that the header *declares*.
Thus, you keep the definition of `rescale_power` in src.cpp. Since every
variable should be defined only once, you have to remove the definition
from myapp.ino.

If for some reason src.cpp cannot know the initial value you would want
to give to `rescale_power`, then live it default-initialized, and assign
the value you want in myapp.ino:

```cpp
void setup() {
    rescale_power = presets[PRESET][4];
}
```

---

**Edit**: In a comment, you wrote:

> I don't get why I can't put `rescale_power = 4` in `myapp.ino` outside
> a function ?

Because it's an assignment. Assignments are statements: they are
executed at run time, and can only be written within functions. For
reference, here are the syntaxes for a declaration, a definition and an
assignment:

```cpp
// Declaration:
extern float rescale_power;

// Definitions:
float rescale_power;      // implicitly zero-initialized
float rescale_power = 2;  // with explicit initialization

// Assignment:
rescale_power = 4;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed the declaration from everywhere except `src.php`. It works for `unit-tests.cpp` ; but it doesn't work for `myapp.ino`: `error: 'rescale_power' was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: @theredled: Did you keep the declaration of `rescale_power` in src.h? Is this file still included in myapp.ino?

Comment: No, I removed it. Now I have a declaration in `src.h` `extern float rescale_power;`, a definition in `src.cpp` `float rescale_power = 2;`.
Now it works! But I don't get why I can't put `rescale_power = 4` in `myapp.ino` outside a function ?

Comment: Edited----------